# Can I please get some help getting this popunder java script to open

Tags: javascript, web, popup

I have a pop under link that I got from edomz that I want to put it on my blog. The problem is that it only opens after someone clicks on a different page. I would like it to open as soon as someone opens my site.

Thanks in advance.
This is the  code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.lookit-quick.com/run.php?user=pacmaniam&js=1&lb=0&pnum=6"></script>
```

PS I have no js experience

Comment: Why would you want to do something so evil to your users?  You know that browsers these days come with built in abilities to block this sort of thing specifically because users found them so annoying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to do so : you could do it through body load event : something similar to that

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
window.open("http://www.lookit-quick.com/run.php?user=pacmaniam&js=1&lb=0&pnum=6")
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

following is the code for opening a popup

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

and in body tag:

```
<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```